# Issue with mule starting up (at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.accept(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:234)

Tags: jetty, mule

mule is not starting up, it tries to start hangs for a while and after some time tries to start from first again like restart. Took the thread dump. There is a warning while analyzing thread dump which says "3 threads are transitively BLOCKED. It's indicating lock is not getting released."  which could be potential issue probably some thing to do with jetty, but not clear what that is.  Here is part of thread dump analysis

```
0x00000000e0f43f40
Object
Held by:
  qtp383251638-61-acceptor-0-ServerConnector@7d75f858{HTTP/1.1}{0.0.0.0:7777}
Threads waiting to take lock:
  qtp383251638-62-acceptor-1-ServerConnector@7d75f858{HTTP/1.1}{0.0.0.0:7777}
  qtp383251638-63-acceptor-2-ServerConnector@7d75f858{HTTP/1.1}{0.0.0.0:7777}
  qtp383251638-64-acceptor-3-ServerConnector@7d75f858{HTTP/1.1}{0.0.0.0:7777}


"qtp383251638-61-acceptor-0-ServerConnector@7d75f858{HTTP/1.1}{0.0.0.0:7777}": running, holding [0x00000000e0f43f40]
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.accept0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.accept(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:422)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.accept(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:250)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector.accept(ServerConnector.java:321)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractConnector$Acceptor.run(AbstractConnector.java:460)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:601)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:532)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Answer (score 1):

Acceptors are always in blocked state when they are not actively accepting connections, that is normal for that kind of thread.

Your issue is elsewhere.
You haven't given enough details about it to troubleshoot though. (sorry)

Comment: thanks for the response. i tried to add full thread dump but due to size restriction not able to attach fully. will try to attach in parts

Answer (score 0):

Resolved the issue from thread dump. There was issue in establishing connection with message broker.

```
nid=0xe128 in Object.wait() [0x00007f41303ef000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.failover.FailoverTransport.oneway(FailoverTransport.java:613)
    - locked <0x00000000ddddecf0> (a java.lang.Object)
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.MutexTransport.oneway(MutexTransport.java:68)
```